# Is the quotient of a Polish TVS Polish?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

The title says it pretty much: Suppose $X$ is a Polish TVS. Let $A$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Is the quotient space $X/A$ Polish with respect to the relative topology?

I know this is true for topological Polish groups from Kechris's paper [Topology and its Applications **58**, 195 (1994)]. As silly it may sound, I couldn't find the above statement in the literature. Could anyone let me know of a reference, please?

Comment: To clarify, you have a reference for a stronger statement, but you are looking for an explicit reference for the weaker one?

Comment: @tomasz I'm not an expert in topology and that's why I'm posing this question. As groups are more structured than TVSs, I think you're understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is, though I don't have literature reference handy.

$X{/}A$ has a standard quotient linear structure (as $A$ is a linear subspace), and like in the case of groups, the operations on the quotient are still continuous.

As $A$ is closed in the Polish $X$, it's a $G_\delta$ and this implies that $0$ in $X{/}A$ has a countable local base (and $\{0\}$ is closed so the quotient is Hausdorff and regular) and so is metrisable (Birkhoff's theorem). It's separable as $X$ is, and $X{/}A$ is its continuous image.

I think that completeness of the quotient will follow from the closedness of $X$ too.

Maybe others do know of a good reference?

Comment: Birkhoff-Kakutani gives you a translation-invariant metric (and maybe a complete one? I don't remember the proof, to be honest, so I'm not sure). You can then easily explicitly define an invariant metric on the quotient (which would be complete if the original one is). My feeling is that the quotient of a completely metrisable TVS should always be completely (pseudo)metrisable, regardless of separability. But I may be way off base, I have almost no experience with non-normed TVS.

Comment: @tomasz I think it is translation invariant indeed. Complete ness I don’t recall either.

Comment: I meant that you can use B-K to deduce that the original Polish TVS has an invariant metric, and then the quotient would have an invariant metric (which I think you can easily check generates the quotient topology, though I haven't written down the details), without the need for separability of the original space.

Comment: Regarding completeness, it is true: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2031907

Comment: @tomasz classic paper by Klee. Nice find.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of a slightly more general statement about abelian (not necessarily Polish) groups.

If $G$ is an abelian, completely metrisable group and $H\leq G$ is a closed subgroup, then $G/H$ is also completely metrisable (in general, if $H$ is not necessarily closed, it is pseudometrisable). (In particular, if $G$ is Polish, so is $G/H$, since separability trivially passes to the quotient.)

Since $G$ is completely metrisable and abelian, by [a variant of the Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem](https://doi.org/10.2307/2031907), its topology is induced by a complete invariant metric $d$. Following that observation, the proof is very standard. I suspect a version of the argument for Frechet spaces should be easy to find in analysis textbooks (local convexity is irrelevant here, as far as I can tell).

Namely, we can then define on $G/H$ the function $\bar d(g+H,g'+H)=\inf_{h\in H} d(g,g'+h)$. Now, $\bar d$ is clearly invariant. It also satisfies triangle inequality:
$$\bar d(g_1+H,g_2+H)+\bar d(g_2+H,g_3+H)=\inf_{h_1,h_2} d(g_1,g_2+h_1)+d(g_2+h_1,g_3+h_2)\geq \inf_{h_1,h_2} d(g_1,g_3+h_2)=\bar d(g_1+H,g_3+H),$$
it is also trivially symmetric (by invariance of $d$) and non-negative. It is also easy to see that if $\bar d(g+H,H)=0$, then $g\in \bar H$, so it is a metric if $H$ is closed (and a pseudometric otherwise).

It is fairly easy to show that $\bar d$ generates the quotient topology, but that is straightforward: the preimage of a $\bar d$-ball around $g+H$ is the union of the $d$-balls of the same radius around all elements of $g+H$, and if any $U\subseteq G$ is open and a preimage of a subset of $G/H$, then it is a $H$-invariant union of $d$-balls, so it is a preimage of a union of $\bar d$-balls.

Completeness of $\bar d$ is also quite standard: let $(g_n+H)_n$ be Cauchy. We may assume without loss of generality (passing to a subsequence) that $\bar d(g_n+H,g_m+H)<2^{-n-1}$ when $n<m$. Let $g_0'=g_0$. Then take $g_1'\in g_1+H$ such that $d(g_0',g_1')<2^{-1}$, $g_2'\in g_2+H$ such that $d(g_1',g_2')<2^{-2}$ etc. Then by triangle inequality it is easy to check that $d(g_n',g_m')<2^{-n}$ when $n<m$, so the sequence $(g_n')_n$ is Cauchy, and so it converges to some $g$. Since $g_n'+H=g_n+H$ for each $n$, it easily follows that $g_n+H\to g+H$.

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm not concerned with the group structure, I see how the proof works. I'm assuming the answer to my specific question is so straightforward that it's not mentioned within standard textbooks. Or do you recall a classic reference?

Comment: @FaridShahandeh: I don't recall any. I checked some books, but unfortunately I didn't find this particular statement. Anyway, the point of my answer is that the only thing that you need is the (abelian) group structure, the vector space structure is irrelevant.